# Default color filling together with HatchFilling

Tags: plotting, filling

How can I use "Filling" in plot with two different styles?

Specifically, I want to change the second "filling" to HatchFill with lines?

```
Plot[{x, 2 x}, {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}, 2 -> Top}]
```

I come up with a complex method as follow:

```
Plot[{x, 2 x}, {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
Plot[{x, 2 x}, {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> {2 -> Top}, 
 FillingStyle -> HatchFilling[]]
Show[{%1,%2}]
```

Is there a simple way to express the two needs in one sec? Thx a lot!

Comment: `Plot[{x, 2 x}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}, 2 -> {Top, Directive[Green, HatchFilling[]]}}]`

Comment: One additional question: is there a directive like HatchFilling to fill a region with dots? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Plot[{x, 2 x}, {x, 0, 1},
 Filling ->
  {1 -> {2},
   2 -> {Top, Directive[ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[2]], HatchFilling[]]}}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{x, 2 x}, {x, 0, 1},
 Filling ->
  {1 -> {2},
   2 -> {Top, 
     Directive[ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[2]], 
      HatchFilling["Vertical"]]}}]
```

[image]

There are many more `HatchFilling` options. See `Documentation`.

**Addendum**

To fill with dots (as per comment) use `PatternFilling`:

```
 Plot[{x, 2 x}, {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}, 2 -> {Top,
     PatternFilling[{"Halftone", ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[2]]}, ImageScaled[1/20]]}}]
```

[image]

You can control the number and size of the points with the
`ImageScaled` - parameter.

Comment: Thanks! BTW, does 97 stand for the color set of the default plot theme? What is the number for the "scientific" theme then?

Comment: Yes, that's the default. With other words, the hatch filling color is the same as the line color. I don't know the number for the "scientific" theme.